# Не работает js скрипт в chrome

Tags: javascript, html

Я написал javascript код для того что-бы при нажатии на элемента в форме появились скрытые элементы. Проблема в том когда открываешь сайт в браузере firefox скрипт отлично работает, но если открыть его в chrome он не работает.

```js
  function focux() {
    document.getElementById('hidden_content').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('hidden_content2').style.display = 'none';
  }

  function focux2() {
    document.getElementById('hidden_content2').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('hidden_content').style.display = 'none';
  }
```

```html
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="" onclick="focux()">1</option>
  <option value="" onclick="focux2()">2</option>
  <option value="">3</option>
</select>

<p id="hidden_content" style="display: none;">Bul focux()</p>
<p id="hidden_content2" style="display: none;">Bul focux2()</p>
```

Comment: onclick на опциях select'а срабатывает только в Firefox'е. Используйте событие onchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите onclick на элементах option и поставьте onchange на элементе select, а там уже задайте вывод элемента в зависимости от значения value.

Например, измените html-верстку:

```
<select id="test" onchange="test();">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

И используйте эту функцию:

```
function test() {
    var id = document.getElementById('test').value;
    if (id == 1) {
        document.getElementById('hidden_content').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('hidden_content2').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if (id == 2) {
        document.getElementById('hidden_content2').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('hidden_content').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

P.S. Также вам очень не помешает привести свой код и namespace хотя бы в относительный порядок. Используйте функции-обертки для однотипных операций.